# iphone getting hours/min/seconds app crashes

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i have this code in my overridden drawRect method

`NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

    NSInteger h = [comp hour];

    NSInteger m = [comp minute];

    NSInteger s = [comp second];

    NSLog(@"%i,%i,%i", h,m,s);

    NSLog(@"test");

    [date release];

    [calendar release];

    [comp release];`

I am calling drawRect using setNeedsDisplay from my custom method (timer based after each 1 secon). It runs only once and then app exit automatically. If i comment out all the code and just write
NSLog(@"test");
then application works ok, it logs "test" after each 1 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three of the objects you're releasing are autoreleased. You shouldn't call `release` on them explicitly.

Comment: how to find which one is autoreleased?

Comment: It's all in the method names. Read this document for details: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB